# Entry Search - Spinning Wheel of Death

Tags: search

Noticed this particular issue with a site. I am currently using EE 2.7.3 and whenever I try doing a search under the "EDIT" section in the search field, I get a spinning wheel of death. Nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in 2.7.3, [documented here](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19977). There's a fix in the bug report as well.